# How to make random.choices truly random (I cannot find it in secrets module)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do an statistical study of an strategy called Martingala. For now I want to practice it many times, adding the results to a list. The problem is that despite being random, it returns me always the same result. I suspect it is because of the random module not being truly random. How can I solve it?

Many thanks.

```
import random
print("ANÁLISIS ESTADÍSTICO DE LA MARTINGALA")
print()
print("La apuesta mínima es 1€")
dinero = int(input("Con cuanto dinero empiezas? "))
muestra = int(input("Tamaño de la muestra: "))
dinero_apostado=1
tiradas=0
datos=list()
while muestra>0:
    while dinero >= dinero_apostado:
        casilla=random.choices([0,1,2],[1,18,18])
        casilla=casilla.pop()
        if casilla == 1:
            dinero = dinero + dinero_apostado
            dinero_apostado = 1
        elif casilla != 1:
            dinero = dinero - dinero_apostado
            dinero_apostado = dinero_apostado * 2
        tiradas+=1
    datos.append(tiradas)
    muestra-=1
print(datos)
```

Comment: random.choices is not a function (AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'choices')

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000: it does exist in more recent versions of Python.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 it was added in Python 3.6 I believe.

Comment: That would explain it. I'm using 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code keeps repeating the same result because you're not resetting any of your variables in between the trials of your algorithm. Once the inner `while` loop's condition becomes `False`, it will remain `False` for each iteration of the outer loop. So the main algorithm doesn't actually run several times. It runs once and then the code just repeats the result of that one run a bunch of times. Using a different random number generator won't help.

Try moving some of your variable initializations inside the outer loop. You may need an extra variable for the amount of money you start with (since `dinero` changes as the game is played). Maybe something like this:

```
dinero_inicial = int(input("Con cuanto dinero empiezas? ")) # new variable used here
muestra = int(input("Tamaño de la muestra: "))
datos=list()
while muestra>0:
    dinero = dinero_inicial         # move some other initializations inside the outer loop
    dinero_apostado = 1
    tiradas = 0
    while dinero >= dinero_apostado:
        casilla=random.choices([0,1,2],[1,18,18])
        casilla=casilla.pop()
        if casilla == 1:
            dinero = dinero + dinero_apostado
            dinero_apostado = 1
        elif casilla != 1:
            dinero = dinero - dinero_apostado
            dinero_apostado = dinero_apostado * 2
        tiradas+=1
    datos.append(tiradas)
    muestra-=1
print(datos)
```